# How to pass multiParams in scalatra

Tags: scala, scalatra

If I want to read a single parameter in a get request in scalatra I can do it as follows:

```
get("mypath/:id") {
 val id = params("id")
...
}
```

According to the scalatra documentation I can also use `multiParams` to get a sequence of parameters:

```
val ids = multiParams("ids")
```

But it does not say how the URL should be formed should I wish to pass more than one parameter. So if I wanted to pass multiple ids what is the format for the URL?

I have tried it with ampersands, commas and semi-colons but to no avail: e.g.

> ../mypath/id1&id2

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs: http://scalatra.org/guides/2.4/http/routes.html

> As an example, let’s hit a URL with a GET like this:
>
> `/articles/52?foo=uno&bar=dos&baz=three&foo=anotherfoo`
>
> Look closely: there are two “foo” keys in there.
>
> Assuming there’s a matching route at `/articles/:id`, we get the
>   following results inside the action:
>
> ```
> get("/articles/:id") {
>   params("id") // => "52"
>   params("foo") // => "uno" (discarding the second "foo" parameter value)
>   params("unknown") // => generates a NoSuchElementException
>   params.get("unknown") // => None - this is what Scala does with unknown keys in a Map
>
>   multiParams("id") // => Seq("52")
>   multiParams("foo") // => Seq("uno", "anotherfoo")
>   multiParams("unknown") // => an empty Seq
> }
> ```

So you would need to name each param. e.g. `/mypath/?ids=id1&ids=id2&ids=id3`

Comment: To me the line in the docs multiParams("id") => Seq("52") implies this approach can be used for multiple parameters. i.e not having to pass the name for each argument. This is what prompted me to asked the question.

Comment: @user79074, is the `foo` parameter in the same example what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed multiple same name parameters in the path and get them through `multiParams`:

```
// http://localhost:8080/articles/id1/id2
get("/articles/:id/:id"){
  println(multiParams("id")) // => Seq("id1", "id2")
}
```